# Pass parameters to a procedure with SQLcmd

Tags: sql-server, variables, stored-procedures

I use this SQL command:

```
 sqlcmd -v first_date="30/09/2015" last_date="15/09/2016"
```

The SQL execute:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[_testProcedure]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO

PRINT 'Finally'
GO
```

And I would like to pass that parameters to a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[_testProcedure]
    WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @F_FIRST_DATE_DT VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @F_LAST_DATE_DT VARCHAR(50)

    SET @F_FIRST_DATE_DT = N'$(first_date)'
    SET @F_LAST_DATE_DT = N'$(last_date)'
```

But it return me an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'first_date'

What is the correct way to pass variables to stored procedure?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your stored procedure doesn't has any input parameters - so you can't pass anything to it without modification of your procedure.

Comment: Should do I declare the parameters at the header? Between `ALTER PROCEDURE` and `AS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will declare `@F_FIRST_DATE_DT` and `@F_LAST_DATE_DT` as input parameters of your stored procedure - you will be able to call it like

```
EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[_testProcedure] 
                         @F_FIRST_DATE_DT = $(first_date), 
                         @F_LAST_DATE_DT = $(last_date)
```

in your script you're running with sqlcmd.

You're getting error because `$()` syntax is valid for accessing external varables only in sqlcmd script, and not in stored procedures.

Comment: I added double quote `"$(first_date)"` and now it works. Thanks